# How to create this list Tile or card design?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to implement this custom tile but cant seem to figure it out this is what I tried.

I have it implemented as a custom widget to make the code shorter in the actual screen. the first one with black over the text and logo is **requested** since they are covered for privacy reasons.

```
class CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget {
String title;
String subtitle1;
String subtitle2;
String imagePath;

CustomListTile({
 required this.title,
 required this.subtitle1,
 required this.subtitle2,
 required this.imagePath,
});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
 double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
 return SizedBox(
   width: screenWidth * 0.9,
   height: screenHeight * 0.2,
   child: Column(
     children: [
       Container(
         height: screenHeight * 0.1,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
               topRight: Radius.circular(10), topLeft: Radius.circular(10)),
           color: Colors.white,
         ),
         child: Center(child: Text(title)),
       ),
        Container(
          height: screenHeight * 0.10,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
               bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
               bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10)),
            color: Colors.blue,
         ),
         child: Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
           child: Row(
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
             children: [
               Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: [
                   Text(subtitle1),
                   Text(subtitle2),
                 ],
               ),
               SizedBox(
                 width: screenWidth * 0.05,
               ),
               ClipOval(
                 child: Container(
                   child: Center(
                      child: Image.asset(imagePath)),
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
  );
 }
}
```

here is my **Homescreen.dart**

```
SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/back5.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: screenWidth * 0.90, // Adjust the width as needed
                height: screenHeight * 0.100, // Adjust the height as needed
                child: ListTile(
                  trailing: ClipOval(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/logo3.png",
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    "testapp",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: MyColors.myBlue,
                      fontFamily: "Arabic",
                      fontSize: screenWidth * 0.04,
                    ),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: MyColors.myBlue,
                        child: Text(
                          "user",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: "Arabic",
                            fontSize: screenWidth * 0.04,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "number",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: "Arabic",
                          fontSize: screenWidth * 0.04,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Handle the tap action here
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code:

```
SizedBox(
                  width: screenWidth * 0.9,
                  height: screenHeight * 0.5,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: screenHeight * 0.1,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(10)),
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        child: Center(child: Text("Hello")),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: screenHeight * 0.25,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10)),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                          child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Text("Hello"),
                                  Text("Hello"),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: screenWidth * 0.05,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Center(child: Text("A")),
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: Colors.white),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

Output: [image]

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you. many thanks

Comment: it works but there is an issue. I cant reduce the white zone size.  its a lot bigger.

check the updated question with your code please

Comment: change first container height to :
`height: screenHeight * 0.05,`